# How to admin samba 4 domain controller from Mac client

Tags: samba, mac

That's my question. I want to admin a ubuntu samba 4 domain controller from mac the same way (as it's possible) i do it with windows with RSAT. Can I do it? Does anybody knows any tool? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as im aware there isn't any software to administer GPO (Group Policy Objects) from a mac and requires windows.

One way would be to install [Vmware Player](http://www.vmware.com/uk/products/player) and install a windows machine inside of that and use it to administer users and GPO's.

Underneath active directory it uses LDAP to authenticate users, so if you aren't interested in administering GPO's you could use a tool like [LDAP browser MAC](http://www.ldapbrowsermac.com/) to manage your users.

You may also need to set up LDAPS to change users passwords and you can find a guide to that on the samba wiki (Google "ssl certificate samba")

Comment: Ok very grateful with your answer. I have the first way working and doing it fine. I will try to implement the second one, i'll report the results. Thanks a lot.